# How to copy file from local to share with JCifs?

Tags: java, samba, jcifs

I can copy file from share to local. But I want to switch, and copy a file from local to share.

```
I am trying this code:
SmbFile oldFile = new SmbFile("c:/tmp/test.xml");
SmbFile newFile = new SmbFile("smb://someone_pc/tmp/test.xml", new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("", username, password));
oldFile.copyTo(newFile);
```

But I am getting an exception on `copyTo` method:

```
Invalid operation for workgroups or servers
```

How should I copy file from local to share?

Answer (score 4):

Complete solution for copying file from local to shared disk over SMB protocol using streams like [Javi_Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36737231/3596127) (writing in parts - solution for large files where it's not possible to load whole file into memory):

```
// local source file and target smb file
File fileSource = new File("C:/example.jpg");
SmbFile smbFileTarget = new SmbFile(smbFileContext, "example.jpg");
// input and output stream
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileSource);
SmbFileOutputStream smbfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(smbFileTarget);
// writing data
try {
    // 16 kb
    final byte[] b  = new byte[16*1024];
    int read = 0;
    while ((read=fis.read(b, 0, b.length)) > 0) {
        smbfos.write(b, 0, read);
    }
}
finally {
    fis.close();
    smbfos.close();
}
```

Comment: jcifs.smb.SmbException: Access is denied.
 at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.checkStatus(SmbTransport.java:542)
 at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:644)
 at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:242)
 at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.send(SmbTree.java:111)
 at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.send(SmbFile.java:729)
 at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open0(SmbFile.java:934)

Were you able to solve this ?

Comment: @Michal Yes, I hadn't this problem (Access is denied). It seems you have not the rights to Smb directory. Can you check your NtlmPasswordAuthentication (for jcifs version 1.x) or your CIFSContext (for jcifs version 2.x)?

Answer (score 2):

It was some time ago I worked with jcifs.
Could you try `newFile.createNewFile();` and then use the `copyTo`.
If that doesn't work, than try `newFile.getOutputStream()` and write the data to this stream instead of using `copyTo`.

Answer (score 1):

I´m a bit late to the party but this could be useful for other persons coming to this question.

I upload files from local to share using streams and it´s working without any problem. My code is:

```
SmbFile remoteFile =  new SmbFile(remotePath, auth);
SmbFileOutputStream out = new SmbFileOutputStream(remoteFile);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(localFile);
out.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(fis));
out.close();
```

Comment: You are loading the whole file on memory. What happens when this is not possible?

Answer (score 1):

An example using Java 1.7's [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class:

```
Path source = Paths.get("c:/tmp/test.xml");
SmbFile newFile = new SmbFile("smb://someone_pc/tmp/test.xml", new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("", username, password));
try (OutputStream out = newFile.getOutputStream())
{
    Files.copy(source, out);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void uploadToSmb(String destinationPath,File localFile){
    public final static byte[] BUFFER = new byte[10 * 8024];
        ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = null;
        SmbFileOutputStream sfos = null;
        try {
            String user = username + ":" + password;
            int lenghtOfFile = (int) localFile.length();
            byte[] data = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(localFile);
            inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
            String path = destinationPath + localFile.getName();
            NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(user);
            remoteFile = new SmbFile(path, auth);
            sfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(remoteFile);
            long total = 0;
            while ((count = inputStream.read(BUFFER)) > 0) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                int percentage = (int) ((total / (float) lenghtOfFile) * 100);
                publishProgress(percentage);
                //  publishProgress((int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                // writing data to file
                    sfos.write(BUFFER,0,count);

            }
                sfos.flush();
                inputStream.close();
                sfos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
      }
```

this code is working Great...